# JSonResponse without array in android

Tags: android, json

I am quite new to use of JavaApi to retrieve data from the server in android.
previously worked with a .php file for retrieving data from the database.

my question is
m getting json response without array like below:

```
{"data":{"param1":true,"param2":3,"param3":"NULL"},"success":"1"}
```

and I want to retrieve the param2 value from this response

in .php we usually get Array value and so it will be easy to work with jsonResponse but with Java API I m not getting any array value.

I tried to convert response string into an array and then retrieve param value but it didn't work.

also searched for the solution but couldn't find any solution

How to do this???

Answer (score 1):

```
{"data":{"param1":true,"param2":3,"param3":"NULL"},"success":"1"}
```

here **data** has JsonObject value

**So parse JSON like this**

```
try {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject("{\"data\":{\"param1\":true,\"param2\":3,\"param3\":\"NULL\"},\"success\":\"1\"}");

        JSONObject data=obj.getJSONObject("data");

        //getting param2 from data

        int param2=data.getInt("param2");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to get data from json response:

```
String response = responseString;

    JSONObject jsonRes = null;
    try {
        jsonRes = new JSONObject(response);
        String valSuccess = jsonRes.getString("success");
        JSONObject dataObj = jsonRes.getJSONObject("data");

        String parm1Val = dataObj.getString("param1");
        String parm2Val = dataObj.getString("param2");
        String parm3Val = dataObj.getString("param3");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```